# How to get "winner" based on row MAX

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to get the header value based on the highest value per row.

For example, given a sheet like:

```
A B C D
-------
1 2 3 4
3 3 1 2
```

I'd like to do reports on the winners of the row. For example something like

```
A B C D | Winner
----------------
1 2 3 4 | D
3 3 1 2 | TIE
```

I know how to pull the top value but I'm not sure how to have it pull from another cell based on the index of the "winning" (highest number) cell in a row.

[image]

Comment: Why is the second row a tie when 3 is the max?

Comment: Oops that's a typo! My bad let me fix

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the following formula is helpful.

`=IF(COUNTIF(A3:E3,LARGE(A3:E3,1))>1,"TIE",INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MATCH(LARGE(A3:E3,1),A3:E3,0)))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula:

```
=LET(x,MAX($A2:$D2),y,COUNTIF($A2:$D2,x),IF(y=1,XLOOKUP(x,$A2:$D2,$A$1:$D$1,,0),"TIE"))
```

**Results**

[image]

Same formula adapted to match your image:

[image]